# How to put arguments in a jchart.Chart class

Tags: python, django, django-views, chart.js

I am trying to make a chart in Django using the **jchart** module and to be able to chose which rows i want to retrieve from the db using the variable *hosp* from my *views.py* to *HomeTotalStudies()* (below)

*views.py*

```
from charts.chartsclass import HomeTotalStudies

def home(request):

    hosp = request.user.userprofile.hospital
    chart = HomeTotalStudies()
    return render .....
```

here is the */charts/chartsclass.py*

```
from jchart import Chart
from jchart.config import (DataSet, Axes, rgba, ScaleLabel, Tick, Tooltips,
                           Legend, LegendLabel, Title, Hover, InteractionModes,
                           ElementLine, ElementPoint, ElementRectangle)

class HomeTotalStudies(Chart):

    chart_type = 'pie'
    responsive = False


    def get_labels(self,**kwargs):
        return ["CT","MG","RF","DX"]

    def get_datasets(self,**kwargs):
        modality = ['CT','MG','RF','DX']
        count = []
        if hosp=='somestring' #this is the variable i want to get from the views.py
            studies = GeneralStudyModel.objects.all()
        else:
            studies = GeneralStudyModel.objects.filter(equipmentattributes__institution_name__exact=hosp)

        for mod in modality:
            cc = studies.objects.filter(modality_type__exact=mod).count()
            count.append(cc)
        data = [count[i] for i in range(len(count))]
        colors = [
            rgba(255,99,132,1),
            rgba(54,162,235,1),
            rgba(255,159,64,1),
            rgba(255,206,86,1)
        ]
        return [DataSet(label="My DataSet",
                        data=data,
                        borderWidth=1,
                        backgroundColor=colors,
                        borderColor=colors)]
```

So, my question is, how can I pass this variable *hosp* from the view to the chart class so that i can make the query to the db table GeneralStudyModel and i retrieve only the rows needed?

Any one has any suggestion / idea / solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yep.

You have two possibilites:

- the hard way: you make an AJAX call that returns an array, and you populate this in JavaScript. This implies to make a JSON view that returns a JSON array
- the easy way: you need to use [`class-based-view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/)'s to make modern application and in your class you override the method `get_context_data()`

like this:

```
class GeneralStudyResultsView(generic.TemplateView):

    template_name='general_study_results.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(GeneralStudyResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Create a variable you fill
        context['my_big_sql'] = GeneralStudyModel.objects.all()
        return context
```

And from there, in your template file (*this is your template file, not a JavaScript file*) `general_study_results.html` add something like:

```
<script>
var myData = 
{% for row in my_big_sql %} 
    {{ row.column }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %};
</script>
```

And then you have all your data in your HTML file ready to be show thanks to `charts.js`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a suitable initialiser to the chart class as follows:

```
class HomeTotalStudies(Chart):

    def __init__(self, hosp, *args, **kwargs):
        self.hosp = hosp
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_datasets(self,**kwargs):
        modality = ['CT','MG','RF','DX']
        count = []
        if self.hosp=='somestring' #this is the variable i want to get from the views.py
            studies = GeneralStudyModel.objects.all()
        else:
            studies = GeneralStudyModel.objects.filter(equipmentattributes__institution_name__exact=self.hosp)
    ...
```

then in your view:

```
from charts.chartsclass import HomeTotalStudies

def home(request):

    hosp = request.user.userprofile.hospital
    chart = HomeTotalStudies(hosp='whatever')
    return render .....
```